# How do you undo loadkeys?

Tags: server

I am running a webserver without a desktop environment and i need to change my keyboard to Cyrillic when I edit the files. The problem is, I cannot exit nano or type any commands.

Comment: You only use it on the local console? When logged in from a desktop/laptop using SSH this shouldn't be an issue…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to know what the previous one was to reload that keymap with loadkeys (or you can load a default keymap with `loadkeys -d`).

As you can't enter that command, you'll need another way to run it (e.g. by configuring a shortcut to do it).  How to do this also depends on what Ubuntu version you use, or whether you already use something like `screen`, `tmux` (or `byobu`). Or you can also bind Cyrillic keys to nano commands (e.g. to save and exit) and make a Cyrillic alias for loading a non-Cyrillic keymap.

Comment: I did not know much about aliases. I should have checked beforehand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As JanC says, you should use loadkeys. Cyrillic is Russian? If so, you then have to load Russian with `loadkeys ru`. to be able to do this, you might have to install console-data with `apt-get install console-data`.